# $\sum{|x_n|}^2,\; \sum{|y_n|}^2$ converge, then the series $\sum{x_ny_n}$ converges absolutely

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

**Question:** $\sum{|x_n|}^2,\; \sum{|y_n|}^2$ converge, then the series $\sum{x_ny_n}$ converges absolutely and $|\sum{x_ny_n}|\leq(\sum{|x_n|}^2)^\frac{1}{2} (\sum{|y_n|}^2)^\frac{1}{2}$

**Ideas**

- I think that by comparison test you can get: $(\sum{|x_n|}^2)^\frac{1}{2} (\sum{|y_n|}^2)^\frac{1}{2}\leq(\sum{|x_n|}^2) (\sum{|y_n|}^2)$ and this converge
- Also by triangle inequality you know this: $|\sum{x_ny_n}|\leq\sum{|x_ny_n|}$ which is true if $\sum{x_ny_n}$ converges absolutely
- To get the proof i think you need to reach this: $\sum{|x_ny_n|}\leq(\sum{|x_n|}^2)^\frac{1}{2} (\sum{|y_n|}^2)^\frac{1}{2}$ (like mixing the triangle inequality and the first result by comparison test

Comment: in my class they didn't teach that yet. This question is to put in practice the things you learn in Series and sequences.

Comment: Are you asking a question? It’s Cauchy-Schwarz and it’s True.

Comment: I suggest you try to prove $$2xy \leq x^2 + y^2$$ using $$(x-y)^2\geq 0.$$ Then you can get $$\sum_{n=1}^N \vert x_n y_n\vert \leq \sum_{n=1}^N x_n^2 + \sum_{n=1}^N y_n^2.$$ Then you can show that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$ holds $$\sum_{n=1}^N \vert x_n y_n\vert \leq C.$$ This means the partial sums are bounded. Then show that the partials sums are monotone increasing and conclude.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Your method answers the title but not the more precise question of the text.

Comment: not really @AnneBauval because mostly because using that cauchy inequality i need to get an expression where $\sum{|x_ny_n|} \; \text{is} \leq$ than something

Comment: Yes it really does. Apply this duplicate to $a_n=|x_n|,b_n=|y_n|.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry, did not read it properly. Missed the part where they wanted to get the specific estimate.

Answer (score 0):

$$(| x | - | y |)^2 \ge 0 \implies | x |^2 + | y | ^2 \ \ge \ 2| xy | $$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (| x_n |^2 + | y_n | ^2 ) \ge  \sum_{k=1}^n \ 2| x_ny_n | $$
Now, $ \sum_{k=1}^{n}  2| x_ny_n | \,$ is a strictly increasing sequence which is bounded above so by Monotone Convergence Theorem it converges.
As always its not particularly useful for you to just be given the answer.

> Often when we use a method to attempt a question, we tend to get obsessed with it and go to great lengths to make it work. If we can't get our method to work it does not necessarily mean it is the wrong approach but it still might be an indication that we want to try something else. This happens to me a lot and I've found that taking a short break to refresh my mind, then coming back to the question and making a list of different ideas to try out without looking at my previous working helps me get past this. Good luck in future questions!

Comment: Your answer is the same as SeverinSchraven's comment, hence my comment to it will be the same: "Your method answers the title but not the more precise question of the text." Severin agreed: "Sorry, did not read it properly. Missed the part where they wanted to get the specific estimate." Moreover, please do not answer to duplicates (the duplicate was mentionned in the comments 2 hours before you edited this).